# Zoomable Sunburst

Tags: javascript, dc.js

I'm trying the Sunburst chart. After struggling with the dimension, it's beginning to show like I wanted.

However, I just realised that selecting slices in the Sunburst doesn't change its shape. It only greys out non-selected slices. On the other hand, when selecting values on an associated chart, the Sunburst reshapes indeed. The very dc.js [example](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/sunburst.html) behaves like this.

Although understanding that the greyed out slices are kept on screen in order for the user to be able to select them, I was expecting the Sunburst to implement that *zoom out* by clicking on the centre, or keeping a reset link outside.

Is there a way to redraw the Sunburst that rolls over the visible slices and hides the non-selected, just like the [D3 Zoomable Sunburst](https://beta.observablehq.com/@mbostock/d3-zoomable-sunburst)?

Comment: Someone requested this feature [here](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/1069) but I guess it has not been implemented yet. In general, crossfilter and dc.js charts don't usually filter themselves, only other charts. However, this could be added as as an optional feature. I think the animation is slightly different from what's supported now but shouldn't be too hard to add.

Comment: I'm fighting my way through dc.sunburstChart and associated crossfilter / dimension / group data, trying to figure out what is the difference in the chart status between filtering on itself and filtering from another chart. Once (if) I get there, I'll be able to produce the zoomable sunburst with little added logic.
I don't think this should be added as a feature, unless a mechanism for zooming out would be produced (clicking on the centre?). Otherwise, users might find themselves locked into a zoomed SB and need to refresh the whole page in order to get out of it.

Comment: It goes all the way to crossfilter: [a group does not observe its own dimension's filters](https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter/wiki/Crossfilter-Gotchas#a-group-does-not-observe-its-dimensions-filters). This is intentional, because you wouldn't want e.g. the other bars to drop away to zero when you brush a bar chart. Also, as you said, you need a way to back out, so a chart like pie/sunburst that fills the whole area needs an escape like clicking on the center hole.

Comment: Following that lead, you can get part of the way there by just supplying a second dimension to the sunburst with the same definition as the one for your group. Now whatever you click on expands to fill the chart. The really cool feature, zooming, is still missing, and I don't think the chart contains any code for animating inward/outward. So I don't think this can be done without modifying the chart. It's probably only a few lines of code, but *which few lines?* :)

Comment: @Gordon I have made a zoomable dc.js sunburst, but you have to choose whether to have the zooming action separate from the filtering or not. Either decision can risk being unintuitive.

Comment: That's interesting, @ialarmedalien. What circumstances do you think you might want to zoom without filtering? Would you consider contributing a PR? Either way, it is different behavior from the rest of dc.js, since no other chart zooms itself or changes shape when it is interacted with. But I can see why it's a popular feature, wow.